# How do I display the feature maps (filtered layers) in a tensorflow CNN?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need some help viewing the feature maps in a plant leaf classification program using TensorFlow.

I have a function that takes in any number of images (size 128x128x3) and convolves the images using some filter (size 3x3x32).

```
layer_conv1 = create_convolutional_layer(input=x,
           num_input_channels=num_channels,
           conv_filter_size=filter_size_conv1,
           num_filters=num_filters_conv1)
print(layer_conv1)
```

The code outputs a tensor as printed: `Tensor("Relu_182:0", shape=(?, 64, 64, 32), dtype=float32)`

I am trying to display an image on the console from the tensor, and I've tried the following code (using matplotlib.pyplot):

```
session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
img = session.run(layer_conv1)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

and

```
""
img = layer_conv1[0,:,:,:].eval(session=session)
""
""
```

which both don't work.

`You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'x_54' with dtype float and shape [?,128,128,3]` is one of the errors that occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define your layer with

```
layer_conv1 = create_convolutional_layer(input=x,...)
```

Here, `x` is a placeholder defined with something like

```
x = tf.Placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 128, 128, 3])
```

When you call `img = session.run(layer_conv1)` you need to feed a value for `x` like with

```
img = session.run(layer_conv1, feed_dict={x: myImage})
```

where `myImage` is a numpy array of shape `[1, 128, 128, 3]` representing your image.

Comment: So feed in the original image? I used this code: `img = session.run(layer_conv1, feed_dict={x:data.train.images[0,:,:,:]})` and now I get the error message: `Cannot feed value of shape (128, 128, 3) for Tensor 'x_64:0', which has shape '(?, 128, 128, 3)'`. Will this show me the 0 index position on the tensor-object layer_conv1?

Comment: Reshape this to (1,128,128,3) with np.expand_dims(data.train.images[0], 0)